# How to iterate over a list in if conditionals?

Tags: python

Trying to iterate over range of numbers (or list) to check if values are equal. Seems very simple, but I cant seem to find a way to do it.

I am trying to use an `if statement` to check scope of items in a 2D array.

```
# check if x is equal to var if added to any number between 0 and 10.

if var == x + any(range(10)): # not how it works, but how I want it to

    # do something
```

After looking into `any()` I realize that It just returns `True` if any item in the iterate is `True`

Comment: I know it's not probably what you want, but for the specific example you give in the question, you could just use chained inequalities `0 <= var - x < 10`. Also note that `10` is not included in `range(10)`, so I use `< 10` instead of `<= 10` which would better match what you *say* you wanted to do. You may want to use `range(11)` in the answers below if 10 should be included in the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `any` this way, also use generator:

```
if any(var==(x+i) for i in range(10)):
    # do something
```

Comment: @Retrnon Happy to help, :-), 

Answer (score 0):

You have to use several Python functions for that:

```
if var in list(map(lambda item: x+item, range(10)))
```

**list**: Casts the parameter into a list object.

**map**: Applies a function (first parameter) to a collection of values (second parameter).

**lambda**: Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this `non-any` version:

```
for i in range(10):
    if var == (x+i):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
if var in x + np.arange(10) :
    # do something
```

Would suffer from floating point problem if your numbers are not integers.